# Configure email envelope "Fam.Doe" <johndoe@email.com>

Tags: civimail

In our organisation people share emailadresses. (Context: sumercamps, children share the emailadres of their parents who register them)

When sending out a bulkmailing and deduping while sending, the envelope of one of the shared emailadresses is used.

I would like to know if it is possible to disable using the name in the envelope in these cases.

Example:

"John Doe" johndoe@email.com

"Mary Doe" johndoe@email.com

Send a bulk mail with deduping rules to these two people will send to one of them using:

"John Doe" johndoe@email.com

It seems better not to use the First and Last name in case of a deduped bulk mail from civicrm.

Is this configurable or wold this require a core change?